# Show Pictures from Database

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Hy.

I want to display pictures from my mysql data base.
Php Code:

```
<body> 
<? 
$dbconn = @mysql_connect(localhost,root,xxx) or exit("SERVER Unavailable"); 
@mysql_select_db(test,$dbconn) or exit("DB Unavailable"); 
echo "Hallo";
$sql = "SELECT pictures FROM pictures where pictures_id = 1"; 

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$dbconn) or exit("QUERY FAILED!"); 

$image = @mysql_result($result,0,"pictures"); 

Header ("Content-type: image/jpg");
echo $image;
mysql_close($dbconn); 
?> 
</body>
```

MySql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pictures` (
  `pictures_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pictures` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pictures_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `pictures` (`pictures_id`, `pictures`) VALUES
(1, too long to write the bytecode)
```

I just inserted manually a picture.

The Error is that nothing occurs.

Comment: `or exit("QUERY FAILED!"); ` is utterly useless. At least use `exit(mysql_error())` so you can see WHY the query failed.

Comment: Supressing errors is even more utterly useless when you are trying to find an error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All string parameters in function calls should be enclosed in quotes.

```
$dbconn = @mysql_connect(localhost,root,xxx);
```

should be

```
$dbconn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','xxx');
```

etc.